Keeps getting failed to read error in azure sdk
I am trying to automate some functions and it involves making use of azure imageanalysis API and pyautogui to click on a specific text based on its coordinates from OCR.
The following is my code:
import base64
import logging
import pyautogui
import asyncio
import io
from azure.ai.vision.imageanalysis import ImageAnalysisClient
from azure.ai.vision.imageanalysis.models import VisualFeatures
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from PIL import Image

async def move_mouse_and_click(text: str, session_id: str):
    logging.info("Starting Image Analysis")
    mongo_service = MongoService()  # Ensure MongoService is initialized with the correct parameters
    image_data_base64 = mongo_service.get_last_screenshot(session_id, offset=1)
    if not image_data_base64:
        logging.error("No image data found")
        return

    try:
        image_data = base64.b64decode(image_data_base64)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to decode base64 image data: {e}")
        return

    logging.info("Image received and decoded successfully")

    # Validate the image data directly
    try:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
        image.verify()  # Verify the image integrity
        logging.info("Image data verified successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Image data is invalid: {e}")
        return

    coordinates = await get_bounding_box_coordinates(text, image_data)
    if coordinates:
        x, y = coordinates[0]  # Assuming the first point is the top-left corner
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, pyautogui.moveTo, x, y, 2)
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, pyautogui.click)
    else:
        logging.error("Text not found in the image")

async def get_bounding_box_coordinates(text: str, image_data: bytes):
    endpoint = settings.vision_endpoint
    key = settings.vision_key
    client = ImageAnalysisClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))
    
    try:
        image_stream = io.BytesIO(image_data)
        result = client.analyze(image_data=image_stream.read(), visual_features=[VisualFeatures.READ])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Image analysis failed: {e}")
        return None

    if result.read and result.read.blocks:
        for block in result.read.blocks:
            for line in block.lines:
                if text in line.text:
                    return line.bounding_polygon
    return None

The image is always successfully validated but keeps getting the error as the following:
2024-06-10 10:54:54,655 - root - INFO - Starting Image Analysis 
2024-06-10 10:54:55,928 - root - INFO - Image received and decoded successfully 
2024-06-10 10:54:55,929 - root - INFO - Image data verified successfully. 
2024-06-10 10:54:55,931 - azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy - 
INFO - Request URL: 'https://ocr-matrix.cognitiveservices.azure.com//computervision/imageanalysis:analyze?api-version=REDACTED&features=REDACTED' Request method: 'POST' Request headers:
        'Content-Length': '547998'
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        'x-ms-client-request-id': 'c5c95c7c-26e9-11ef-a236-0242560eba69'
        'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-ai-vision-imageanalysis/1.0.0b2 Python/3.11.7 (Linux-6.5.0-35-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35)'
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'REDACTED' A body is sent with the request 2024-06-10 10:54:59,099 - azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy - INFO - Response status: 200 Response headers:
        'Content-Length': '55770'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        'request-id': '65f22858-bbe1-4001-844f-d8810a2ce719'
        'ms-vision-response-time-input-received': 'REDACTED'
        'ms-vision-response-time-input-processed': 'REDACTED'
        'api-supported-versions': 'REDACTED'
        'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': 'REDACTED'
        'CSP-Billing-Usage': 'REDACTED'
        'apim-request-id': 'REDACTED'
        'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
        'x-content-type-options': 'REDACTED'
        'x-ms-region': 'REDACTED'
        'Date': 'Mon, 10 Jun 2024 05:24:58 GMT' [ WARN:0@68.254] global /croot/opencv-suite_1691620365762/work/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('x'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity 2024-06-10 10:55:00,136 - root - ERROR - Error occurred: Failed to read x because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

I tried saving the image directly to my system from the database to see if the file is corrupted, but that's not the case since I am being able to view it.

use this reference for azure-ai-vision-imageanalysis

@Sampath
A bit confused here. I am using the latest version, installed it with azure-ai-vision-imageanalysis. The imports remain the same and doesn't have to replace azure.ai.vision with azure.ai.vision.image. I referred to the latest documentation while writing the code. Please clarify.

the error says you're trying to read an image file whose path is "x". why? -- code is incomplete. [mre] required. there is no direct use of OpenCV, and there is no pyautogui call that would use it. read the [mre] article thoroughly. you can [edit] your post.

add to your code if __name__ == "__main__":     # Example image path     image_path = "C://Users//hello.png"     logger.info("Starting Image Analysis")     logger.info("Analyzing image...")     analyze_image(image_path) and

add ```# Azure Computer Vision credentials
try:
endpoint = "https://Computervisionname.cognitiveservices.azure.com"
key = "ComputervisionKey"
except KeyError:
print("Missing environment variable 'VISION_ENDPOINT' or 'VISION_KEY'")
exit()
Create an Image Analysis client for synchronous operations
client = ImageAnalysisClient(
endpoint=endpoint,
credential=AzureKeyCredential(key),
logging_enable=True  # Enable logging to troubleshoot
)```

@Niusoski have to added my code to your code and tried again

There is an issue with how you're handling the image data before passing it to the Azure Image Analysis API.

I have refered this msdoc .
To reslove the image file sample.jpg is in one of the supported formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, WEBP, ICO, TIFF, or MPO. The image file sample.jpg in this case exists in the specified path.

When loading the image file into a bytes object image_data, ensure that the file is read correctly in binary mode rb. Use a try-except block to catch any file-related exceptions such as FileNotFoundError or PermissionError when reading the file.
The below code is to analyze an image using Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision API for optical character recognition (OCR) and then interact with the desktop using pyautogui based on the OCR results.
import os
import sys
import logging
import pyautogui
from azure.ai.vision.imageanalysis import ImageAnalysisClient
from azure.ai.vision.imageanalysis.models import VisualFeatures
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential


logger = logging.getLogger("azure")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


try:
    endpoint = "https://Computervisionname.cognitiveservices.azure.com"
    key = "ComputervisionKey"
except KeyError:
    print("Missing environment variable 'VISION_ENDPOINT' or 'VISION_KEY'")
    exit()


client = ImageAnalysisClient(
    endpoint=endpoint,
    credential=AzureKeyCredential(key),
    logging_enable=True 
)


def analyze_image(image_path):
    try:
        with open(image_path, "rb") as f:
            image_data = f.read()

       
        result = client.analyze(
            image_data=image_data,
            visual_features=[VisualFeatures.READ]
        )

       
        if result.read is not None:
            for line in result.read.blocks[0].lines:
              
                word = line.words[0].text
               
                pyautogui.click(100, 100)
                print(f"Clicked on '{word}' at coordinates (100, 100)")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    image_path = "C://Users//hello.png"
    logger.info("Starting Image Analysis")
    logger.info("Analyzing image...")
    analyze_image(image_path)





